# How to discard incoming event in Socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, volatile

Hi I am trying to make a tracker app and I'm using socket.io for both server and client. On my client app, I want to disregard `message` event whenever my browser is not on focus. my code is like this for the client app :

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
const [browserState, setBrowserState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected');
      socket.on("message", payload => {
        //payload need to be passed to Map component
        console.log(payload);
      });
    });
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
      document.onvisibilitychange = function(){
        setBrowserState(document.visibilityState)
      }
      if(browserState === 'hidden') socket.volatile.emit("message", payload => payload)
  },[browserState]);
```

and on my server is just simply:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('message', (payload)=>{
        console.log(payload)
        io.emit('message', payload)
    });
```

The problem is on the client-side for the code `socket.volatile.emit("message", payload => payload)`. if I use `socket.volatile.on` it's working. but I still receive `message` event on the client. if I use `socket.volatile.emit` the server is crashing.

Additional Question: is it okay if my client side `io.protocol = 5` and my server is `io.protocol = 4`?

I'm really new to this. Please advise. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be discarded easily by not replying to incoming sockets

```js
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('message', (payload)=>{
        console.log(payload)
        // removed this line io.emit('message', payload)
    });
```